# Pagination of an complex object into DTO. JPA @Query

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-data-jpa, pagination, entitymanager

I have the following query to take some data regarding two entities in the same time and I receive an error.

```
@Query(value = "select new base.models.HRTableEntity( yr.user.gid,  yr.user.id,  yr.user.lastName || ' ' || yr.user.firstName,  yr.user.position,  yr.user.created,yr.genericField1,yr.genericField2) from YearlyReview yr where yr.year = :yr and yr.user.realDepartment = :dep and yr.user.city = :ct",
            countQuery = "select count(yr.id) from YearlyReview yr where yr.year = :yr and yr.user.realDepartment = :dep and yr.user.city = :ct",
            nativeQuery = false)
    Page<HRTableEntity> getAllTableEntity(Pageable pageRequest, @Param("yr") int year, @Param("dep") String department, @Param("ct") String location);
```

I call this cunction with default Sort (`gid: ASC`) and receive the following error

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: gid of: base.entities.YearlyReview
```

Repo interface:

```
public interface PageableYearlyReview extends CrudRepository<YearlyReview, UUID>
```

Yearly review have a member (user) of type ApplicationUser and I want to put information into DTO from yr.user.gid into HRTableEntry.gid.

What is the right way to do that ?

EDIT:
function call:

```
crunRepoYearTable.getAllTableEntity(PageRequest.of(pageNo - 1, pageSize, sort), year, realDepartment, user.getCity())
```

sort building

```
sortDir.equalsIgnoreCase(Sort.Direction.ASC.name()) ? Sort.by(sortedField).ascending() : Sort.by(sortedField).descending();
```

Entity structure:

```
public class YearlyReview {
    @Id
    private UUID id;
    private int year;
    @OneToOne
    private ApplicationUser user;
....
}
public class ApplicationUser {
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String gid;
.....
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved:

for sort by gid need to send from the fronted like this `user.gid`. User is required to refer at AppUser and gid to access information. And change interface like this
`public interface PageableYearlyReview extends CrudRepository<ApplicationUser, String>`